# numpy reshaping a 2D matrix into an array of symmetric matrix (3D array) without loop

Tags: python, numpy

Consider I have a 2D array in the following form

```
D = [
 [A11,A21,A31,A22,A23,A33],
 [B11,B21,B31,B22,B23,B33],
 [C11,C21,C31,C22,C23,C33]
]
```

in which each `D[i]` is a representation of a symmetric matrix.

The symmetric matrix can be reshaped as

```
[
 [[A11,A21,A31
   A21,A22,A23
   A31,A23,A33]],

 [[B11,B21,B31
   B21,B22,B23
   B31,B23,B33]],

 [[C11,C21,C31
   C21,C22,C23
   C31,C23,C33]]
]
```

So `D[i]` is a list of values for the lower triangular part of i-th symmetric matrix (with diagonals )

It's easy to just perform iterative loop by starts with `result = np.zeros(3,3,3)` then we fill the entries.

Note that I don't need to compute correlation or etc since the values for covariance matrix is already given. I simply want to reshape the 2D into 3D with certain constraint (symmetric and correct indexed)

I'm wondering if there is more efficient way without using loop ? Thanks

Comment: There's a collection of `tri` functions for mapping upper or lower triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in 3 steps (starting with one symmetric matrix for simplicity):

Assuming there is a single vector d0 = D[0]

```
d0 = D[0]  # [A11,A21,A31,A22,A23,A33]
```

First create an empty matrix

```
r = np.zeros([3, 3])  # note: any size will do
```

Assign d0 to the upper part of the matrix

```
upper_tri = ~np.tri(3, 3, -1, dtype=bool)
# [[ True,  True,  True],
#  [False,  True,  True],
#  [False, False,  True]]

r[upper_tri] = d0
# [[A11,A21,A31],
#  [ 0 ,A22,A23],
#  [ 0 , 0 ,A33]]
```

Then transpose the result and assign it to itself, but apply the mask that matches only the lower triangle:

```
lower_tri = ~upper_tri
r[lower_tri] = r.T[lower_tri]
# [[A11,A21,A31
#   A21,A22,A23
#   A31,A23,A33]]
```

---

You can than extend this approach using broadcasting, but it's quite tricky. You need to transpose each input and output matrix. This is because the approach that applies to scalars (e.g. A21 is a single scalar here) would also apply to vectors

```
d0 = D.T  # [ [A11, B11, C11], [A21, B21, C21], [A31, B31, C31]... ]

N = 3  # as batch size to avoid confusion
r = np.zeros([3, 3, N])

upper_tri = ~np.tri(3, 3, -1, dtype=bool)  # same as before
r[upper_tri] = d0

lower_tri = ~upper_tri
r[lower_tri] = r.transpose([1, 0, 2])[lower_tri]

r = r.transpose([2, 0, 1])
```

Comment: This is a great solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I actually had a similar problem a while ago. I saw your question and decided to take another crack at it but with a general solution (useful for dimensions of 3 or greater). I could not find a way to do it without *any* loops (sorry), but it is pretty simple and could be defined as a function with the array and dimension as parameters

**Solution**
Here is the code I used to produce matrices of the type you are asking for from an array like the one you have (note that I just removed the letters and am using ints for purposes of demoing). It does use nested loops still.

```
import numpy as np

D = [
 [11,21,31,22,23,33],
 [11,21,31,22,23,33],
 [11,21,31,22,23,33]
]

d = 3 # dimension
N = 3 # number of sets (A, B, C) or len(D)

# index offset matrix to index from D
offsets = np.zeros((d, d), dtype=int)

# adjustments to offset matrix at each i,j index
adj = np.arange(d-2, 0, -1)
for i in range(1, d-1):
    offsets[i:, i:] += adj[i-1]

cov = np.empty((N, d, d), dtype=int)

# iterate over A, B, C
for n in range(N):
    for i in range(d):
        for j in range(d):
            cov[n, i, j] = D[n][i+j+offsets[i, j]]

print(cov)
```

This prints

```
[[[11 21 31]
  [21 22 23]
  [31 23 33]]

 [[11 21 31]
  [21 22 23]
  [31 23 33]]

 [[11 21 31]
  [21 22 23]
  [31 23 33]]]
```

And if you have a larger set:

```
D = [
 [11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 36, 44, 45, 46, 55, 56, 66],
 [11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 36, 44, 45, 46, 55, 56, 66],
 [11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 36, 44, 45, 46, 55, 56, 66]
]

d = 6
N = 3
offsets = np.zeros((d, d), dtype=int)
adj = np.arange(d-2, 0, -1)
for i in range(1, d-1):
    offsets[i:, i:] += adj[i-1]

cov = np.empty((N, d, d), dtype=int)
for n in range(N):
    for i in range(d):
        for j in range(d):
            cov[n, i, j] = D[n][i+j+offsets[i, j]]

print(cov)
```

You get:

```
[[[11 21 31 41 51 61]
  [21 22 23 24 25 26]
  [31 23 33 34 35 36]
  [41 24 34 44 45 46]
  [51 25 35 45 55 56]
  [61 26 36 46 56 66]]

 [[11 21 31 41 51 61]
  [21 22 23 24 25 26]
  [31 23 33 34 35 36]
  [41 24 34 44 45 46]
  [51 25 35 45 55 56]
  [61 26 36 46 56 66]]

 [[11 21 31 41 51 61]
  [21 22 23 24 25 26]
  [31 23 33 34 35 36]
  [41 24 34 44 45 46]
  [51 25 35 45 55 56]
  [61 26 36 46 56 66]]]
```

**Notes**
This requires your input array D follow the pattern

```
A11, A12, A13, A14, A22, A23, A24, A33, A34, A44
```

as in your 3 dimensional question.

I found this solution by mapping out the indices from D onto the matrix desired, and found that they were matrix indices plus some offset for submatrices within:

```
# [[i+j,  i+j,   i+j,   i+j,   i+j ],
#  [i+j, i+j+3, i+j+3, i+j+3, i+j+3],
#  [i+j, i+j+3, i+j+5, i+j+5, i+j+5],
#  [i+j, i+j+3, i+j+5, i+j+6, i+j+6],
#  [i+j, i+j+3, i+j+5, i+j+6, i+j+6]]
```

These offsets are start at 0, then as i,j increase they increase by 3, then 2, then 1. This pattern scales with higher dimensions.

Long answer but I hope it helps, I definitely have seen and had this problem before.

Cheers

Comment: Hi; thanks for the detailed solution; it turns out you can do in a very efficient way avoiding the nested loop; see the accepted solutions. Hope this can help you in your projects as well !